# How in Java convert async code to sync without excessive boilerplate

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronization, future

I feel so silly posting this question, sure there is an obvious answer, but spent pair of hours trying to guess how to did this with no luck. Probably community will help.

My question: is there any standard mechanism in Java for converting async code to sync one. For example (from, surprisingly, real code), its in Scala, but my question about Java, think of this as of pseudocode (btw in Scala it wont work):

```
var finalWorld:WorldModel = null
LifeActors.run(world, new WorldModelListener {
  override def worldUpdated(world: WorldModel) = {
    finalWorld = world
  }
}, 3) //3 iterations
val alive = finalWorld.getElements.filter(_.isAlive)
```

I want to have something like this:

```
val superFuture = LifeActors.run(world, new WorldModelListener {
    override def worldUpdated(world: WorldModel) = {
      setSuperFutureValue(world)
    }
}, 3) //3 iterations
val alive = superFuture.getValue() //Blocks until is ready
```

I see futures are used as objects running some process which returns result (and future completes). My problem is that I do not want to use cumbersome variable which is accessed from another thread's scope. Is there something like future with a state? Or this does not make sense at all?

Comment: This depends entirely on the apis you use. If you have a `java.util.concurrent.Future` you can call its `get` method to block. You can do the same for `CompletableFuture`. Scala's future (or promise) type should also have such a method.